# using variable name instead of it's value with JavaScript and use it to change an "Object" key identifier

Tags: javascript

My question is how to change or use the variable name instead of value;
I want to use this snippet:

```js
jsonData.forEach((data)=>{
      data.newName= data.api_name;
      delete data.api_name;
})
```

to change the incoming JSON data's key identifier and get that "oldName" from a variable like this

```js
var api_name = "fName";
```

So for example if this data comes from JSON:

```js
[{
  "fName": "John",
  "lname": "Smith"
} {
  "fName": "Jane",
  "lname": "hardy"
}]
```

and want to have this:

```js
[{
  "person_name": "John",
  "lname": "Smith"
} {
  "person_name": "Jane",
  "lname": "hardy"
}]
```

but if I do it like the snippet I will get error because the JSON doesn't have api_name as it's key identifier.
I hope that I explained enough.
appreciate any help

Comment: Do you have to mutate the original object? Why not just `map` to a new object?

Comment: JS 101 - `data[api_name]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `data[api_name]` instead of `data.api_name` . Read more about [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).

```js
let jsonData = [{
  "fName": "John",
  "lname": "Smith"
},{
  "fName": "Jane",
  "lname": "hardy"
}];

let api_name = "fName";

jsonData.forEach((data)=>{
   data.newName= data[api_name];
   delete data[api_name];
})

console.log(jsonData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with data[newName]= data[api_name];

eg 
newName= 'fName';

api_name='apiName'